# Flutter Web RawKeyboardListener 'escape' not working in Fullscreen

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I want to use the 'escape' key in Flutter web to change the widget. The issue that I have is, when in fullscreen my RawKeyboardListener doesn't detect the escape key pressed, unlike when not in fullscreen. I was wondering how to rectify this:

Here is my fullscreen function:

```
  void goFullScreen() {
    document.documentElement!.requestFullscreen();
    
  }
```

Here is my RawKeyboardListener:

```
RawKeyboardListener(
      autofocus: true,
      focusNode: FocusNode(),
      onKey: (event){
        if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.exit)) {
          print('escape pressed');
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem with this as well, what helped is listening to the document onFullscreenchange events:

```
 document.documentElement?.onFullscreenChange.listen((event) {
      
      if (document.fullscreenElement==null) {
        print("do something");
      }
    });
```

It's in the documentation for the fullscreenElement on the mozilla website. When the full screen is existed the fullscreenElement variable is set to null.

Comment: This worked for me thanks.  I had to put it in the build method because when I put it in the class I got an error.  Is there a way to not put it in the build method?