# How to detect esc-key was pressed in flutter web when in fullscreen?

Tags: flutter, video-player

I'm building a web-app in flutter with a video player with the video_player package. My RawKeyboardListener doesnt detect the esc-key when it is pressed in fullscreen. I tried the following

```
RawKeyboardListener(
      focusNode: focusNode,
      autofocus: true,
      child: widget.child,
      onKey: (key) {
        if(key.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.escape)) {
          print("test");
        }
      ...
```

That is only working when you press escape and are not in fullscreen mode.

I already found this answer here:

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70739310/flutter-web-rawkeyboardlistener-escape-not-working-in-fullscreen)

In one answer it says you have to use the following code:

```
    document.documentElement?.onFullscreenChange.listen((event) {
      
      if (document.fullscreenElement==null) {
        print("do something");
      }
    });
```

but I'm not sure where to insert the code.

I tried it in the initState method like this:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if(document.documentElement!= null) {
      print("A");
      document.documentElement!.onFullscreenChange.listen((event) {
        print("B");
        if (document.fullscreenElement==null) {
          print("do something");
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

but it is not working, it prints the "A" but nothing else.

Also I tried at the beginning of the buil-method. What also didnt helped.

I am using google chrome for testing my web app, dont know if this changes anything - of course i want my app to run in all browsers.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Thank you.